# How to organize partitions by auto increment and date?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-partitioning

I have a game in which battles between rivals take place.

Information on the battles is stored in one table.
Information on the course of the battle is stored in another table.

Information about the battle that was a few days ago is not needed by anyone and it must be cheaply destroyed.
I decided to do this with the help of partitions and a scheduler.

Everything works great, but the solution itself is still confusing.
Maybe I invented a bicycle and there is a more elegant solution.

Please tell him a simpler solution.

Thanks.

Battle

```
CREATE TABLE `battle` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attacker_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `defender_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=N DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`id`)
(PARTITION `d200412` VALUES LESS THAN (2004130000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `d200413` VALUES LESS THAN (2004140000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `d200414` VALUES LESS THAN (2004150000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

Battle frame

```
CREATE TABLE `battle_data` (
   `battle_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `frame` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `events` blob NOT NULL,
   `add` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (`battle_id`,`frame`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
  PARTITION BY RANGE (`battle_id`)
 (PARTITION `d200412` VALUES LESS THAN (2004130000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION `d200413` VALUES LESS THAN (2004140000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION `d200414` VALUES LESS THAN (2004150000000000000) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

Scheduler

```
CREATE DEFINER=`main`@`%` EVENT `battle` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-07-10 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN

SET @id_base = '%y%m%d';
SET @id_tail = '0000000000000';

SET @add_name = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), @id_base);
SET @add_less = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, @id_base);

SET @drop_name = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, @id_base);

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `battle` ADD PARTITION IF NOT EXISTS (PARTITION d', @add_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', @add_less, @id_tail, '))');
PREPARE query FROM @sql; EXECUTE query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `battle` DROP PARTITION IF EXISTS d', @drop_name);
PREPARE query FROM @sql; EXECUTE query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `battle_data` ADD PARTITION IF NOT EXISTS (PARTITION d', @add_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', @add_less, @id_tail, '))');
PREPARE query FROM @sql; EXECUTE query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `battle_data` DROP PARTITION IF EXISTS d', @drop_name);
PREPARE query FROM @sql; EXECUTE query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `battle` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @add_name, @id_tail);
PREPARE query FROM @sql; EXECUTE query; DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Stuffing a BIGINT with both auto_increment and a date seems fragile.

Do you need an auto_increment at all?  That is, do you have some other combination of columns that is unique?

Assuming you have keep an ordinary auto_inc, plus another column (`dt`) that is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, you can do this

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, dt)

PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(dt)) ...
```

Then `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` will be happy, and so with the auto_inc.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for more discussion, including why to have a `future` partition.

Comment: Hi, we followed a similar approach like you suggested. Primary key is (id,date field) and delete partition by date. We r using MariaDB. Recently we are observing some exceptions in our UAT env. Id crossed the range. We are using BigInt and right now its NOT even close to the max valie of bigint. Is it not recommended to use bigint(which is auto increment) as part of primarykey on a table having paritions.

Comment: @GaneshP - It's OK for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` to be either `INT` or `BIGINT`.  Perhaps you should start a new Question with your specific implementation and concerns.  Let's not confuse it with BigTon's situation.